# Does it still make sense to create a helper method when it will only be called once?

Tags: c#, methods, coding-style

I frequently find myself creating methods to hold small (<50 lines) algorithms. However, when I first learned methods, we were constantly taught that they were a way to condense/clean up code by housing commonly used code snippets inside a block.

I like to use methods not only for that purpose, but to house small snippets so that my main method is clean and understandable, and the "meat" of the code is hidden within those methods. Stylistically, is this incorrect?

Comment: `clean up code` and `clean and understandable`.  Aren't these complimentary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with breaking up a large method into smaller ones to allow for readability.

It has several benefits, in particular if you keep each method in a single level of abstraction - making the large method read fluently and making each small method simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Another useful side effect is that it makes tracking down the problematic bit of code based on a stack trace a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not incorrect. There are multiple goals you should have while writing code. Not repeating code by consolidating it into reusable classes and methods speaks to *Maintainability*. Factoring out items of work into spearate methods improves *Readability*, which also happens to help Maintainability down the road.

Like all things, there is a balance to seek. Having to mentally traverse too many levels of a call stack to understand an algorithm or find a defect can become a drawback. But if a method is on the order of 50 lines, I find it difficult to believe you would hit this case.

Answer (score 0):

Stylistically, at least from my experience, this is not incorrect. The reason I say this is that a program, if written by one or one hundred programmers will be composed and completed by the talents and experiences of that programmer / programmers. What this means is that there are a large number of ways to solve the problem and the question you should ask yourself is did my implementation work? Did it complete the task / feature? If so, then great!

Because you are concerned with style, I will refer you to [Uncle Bob's SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), as many others have done so with similar questions on style. You mentioned having an algorithm that is composed of <50 lines of code in a single method, I would argue to try following Uncle Bob's Single Responsibility (the 'S' in S.O.L.I.D) principle as best as you can, when you can. This will challenge you to look at that that <50 line-in-a-single-method algorithm and consider breaking it up into more methods that focus on doing one thing, and one thing well. That way you can achieve testability and readability. These are always two things that will go a long way toward "good style".